# What is the sum of all integers between 17 and 325 that are NOT divisible by either the number 7 or the number 11?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the sum of all integers between 17 and 325 that are NOT divisible by either 
the number 7 or the number 11? Sigma notation and other inference/logic rules must be used to solve this problem.

A couple of my friends got 41289 as a final answer while me and a few others got 46902. Could someone please clarify?

Comment: Find the sum of all integers between 17 and 325, subtract the sums of the multiples of 7 and 11, then add back in the sums of multiples of 77.

Comment: The answer should be 41289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to sum all the integers between 17 and 325, then subtract out multiple of 7 and 11, then add back in elements you double subtracted, i.e 77.

Here's some Python code to check your answer, as this is annoying to do by hand.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(17,326,1)
b = np.arange(17, 325, 7)
c = np.arange(17, 326, 11)
d = np.arange(17, 326, 77)

print((np.sum(a)) - np.sum(b) - np.sum(c) + np.sum(d))
```